# What would make this HashSet implementation fail?

Tags: c#, hashset

In order to make my life easier dealing to strings, I want to use a hashset initialized with StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.

But sometimes, I need to make an operation on all items.

**This is clearly not the way I will achieve my goal for obvious performance reasons,** but I'd like to know if this code makes sense, especially the "Set" part of the index, and how it could cause unwanted side effects on the collection.

Here is the HashSet implementation:

```
public class MyHashSet<T> : HashSet<T>
{
    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (T t in this)
            {
                if (i == index)
                    return t;
                i++;
            }
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
        }
        set
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (T t in this)
            {
                if (i == index)
                {
                    this.RemoveWhere(element => element.Equals(t));
                    this.Add(value);
                    return;
                }
                i++;
            }
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }

    public MyHashSet()
    {

    }

    public MyHashSet(IEnumerable<T> collection)
        : base(collection)
    {

    }
    public MyHashSet(IEnumerable<T> collection, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
        : base(collection, comparer)
    {

    }
    public MyHashSet(IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
        : base(comparer)
    {

    }
}
```

In what conditions isn't it safe?

Comment: Why would you want an integer indexer on a HashSet?

Comment: Using an index on a collection that has no implicit order is pointless and stupid. Any favorable results you are seeing are implementation specific and mainly coincidental.

Comment: What is your implementation of `RemoveWhere`?

Comment: @spender ok, now how would you make an operation on every item of a hashset collection? (Apart from iterating on it and adding each item to a new hashset collection)

Comment: @Servy it's the HashSet one

Comment: @GianT971 You `foreach` over the collection to perform an operation on every item.  You don't need to add them to another collection to do that.

Comment: @Servy really? Maybe I wasn't clear enough: I want to modify the items. And if I recall, we can't modify the item represented by a foreach variable

Comment: @spender I renew my question, what would you do to modify all the items of the collection?

Comment: @GianT971 Sure you can modify loop variable of a `foreach` loop, at least assuming it's not a value type, as then you'd be modifying a copy, and assuming it's a mutable type to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In what conditions isn't it safe?

Any.  You're trying to access the items in a `HashSet` by index, but they have no logical index.  The order in which they are iterated is arbitrary and cannot be relied on, so the method doesn't make sense, at a conceptual level, under any circumstances.

If you want to be able to access items by index then use a collection that is ordered, such as a `List`.